# Implicit function theorem of ${ x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 }+{ z }^{ 2 }=yf\left( \frac { z }{ y } \right) $

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

If $z=z(x,y)$ This implicitly given by  ${ x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 }+{ z }^{ 2 }=yf\left( \frac { z }{ y }  \right) $

I need to prove $({ x }^{ 2 }{ -y }^{ 2 }{ -z }^{ 2 })\frac { \partial z }{ \partial x } +2xy\frac { \partial z }{ \partial y } =2xz$

Well I tried to calculate $\frac { \partial z }{ \partial x }$ and $\frac { \partial z }{ \partial y }$ but i supposed that i´m doing wrong something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question states, you have to use the implicit function theorem. One formulation of it as I recall is as follows:

Given $F(x,y,z)=0$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{F_x}{F_z}$,   $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -\frac{F_y}{F_z}$, etc...

In your problem, you can write
\begin{align*}
F(x,y,z) = yf\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - x^2-y^2-z^2.
\end{align*}
From there, you can see that
\begin{align*}
 F_x &= -2x, \\
 F_y &= f\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)+y\left(-\frac{z}{y^2}\right)f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)-2y = f\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)-\frac{z}{y}f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)-2y,\\
F_z &= f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z.
\end{align*}
Using the implicit function theorem, we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &= -\frac{F_x}{F_z} = -\frac{-2x}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} &= -\frac{F_y}{F_z} = -\frac{f\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)-\frac{z}{y}f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)-2y}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}.
\end{align*}

The right hand side of your expression (the one you have to show) becomes:
\begin{align*}
LHS &= \frac{2x(x^2-y^2-z^2)}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}
-2xy\frac{f\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)-\frac{z}{y}f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)-2y}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}\\
&= \frac{2x(x^2-y^2-z^2)-2x\overbrace{yf\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)}^{ x^2+y^2+z^2}+2xzf^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)+4xy^2}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}\\
&= \frac{2x(x^2-y^2-z^2)-2x(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2xzf^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)+4xy^2}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}\\
&= \frac{-4xy^2-4xz^2+2xzf^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)+4xy^2}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}\\
&=\frac{-4xz^2+2xzf^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z} = \frac{2xz\left(-2z+f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)\right)}{f^\prime\left(\frac{z}{y}\right) - 2z}\\
LHS &= 2xz.
\end{align*}

Which is what you needed to show. This problem required a bit of chain rule as well as some substitutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So you use the chains rule in $f\left( \frac { z }{ y }  \right)$, because its a function that depend of $z$ y $y$, right?

Comment: @KennethDíaz, yes. But notice that $f\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)$ only depends on $z$ and $y$ so yes, I used the chain rule. I used product rule (and chain rule) for $yf\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)$.